# Moving and linking attachments to Access database

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am designing a MS-Access database to be used by multiple facilities for projects updates.  I want them to be able to provide updates and include any relevant attachments as well.  I understand that attaching PDFs or other files is a bad idea and would bloat the database.  Now my question:

Is there a way to allow users to select a file (pdf) while on one of the forms and make Microsoft Access copy the chosen file to a central location on the server and then link to the file?  This way all attachments will be located together and the risk of a user deleting the original file is not important.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I only have one question; why Access?

Comment: As opposed to what?  I'm not much of a programmer, but I know how to use SQL and specifically Microsoft Access.

Comment: Please add details about what you have in mind for *"link to the file"*.

Comment: An even better idea is to use MS Access with SQL Server (Express) and then use SQL Server FileStream. This way users won't have access to the actual file folder after they use your application to insert/upload files.